# Checkstyle Maven plugin execution doesn't fail on error when using google_checks

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I'm using the [Maven Checkstyle plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin) in version 3.0.0 and Checkstyle 6.18.

This is my initial configuration:

```
<properties>
    <maven.checkstyle.plugin.version>3.0.0</maven.checkstyle.plugin.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Running `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle` will fail the build since there are checkstyle errors. This is expected.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check (default-cli) on project demo: Failed during checkstyle execution: There are 311 errors reported by Checkstyle 6.18 with sun_checks.xml ruleset. -> [Help 1]
```

However, when I use `google_checks.xml` [which comes bundled with the Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#configLocation) the build succeeds without any error (`target/checkstyle-report.xml` still shows the issues though).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
        <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My expectation would be that the build fails when I use the `google_checks.xml` configuration. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE (04.05.2018):** I've raised [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCHECKSTYLE-351) for this.

Comment: Can you verify the using Checkstyle's CLI with google configuration produces violations? If so, then your maven configuration is the problem.

Comment: I know that Maven is the issue. I'm trying to figure out what exactly is wrong because it works fine for the default Sun checks. Running Checkstyle CLI works for any configuration.

Answer (score 11):

In google_checks.xml, the severity is marked as failure. Changing that to error causes the check to fail.

Original:

```
<property name="severity" value="warning"/>
```

Updated:

```
<property name="severity" value="error"/>
```

In your Maven configuration, you can also tweak on which severity to fail:

```
<configuration>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
    <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
</configuration>
```